# Check if a datetime field is equal to Date.today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to check if an assignment's due_date (datetime data type) is equal to Date.today. The logic I need help with is the 'due_date: Date.today' section. Thanks in advance.

```
@student_assignments = StudentAssignment.joins(:assignment).where(assignments: { due_date: Date.today })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.where("DATE(assignments.due_date) = ?", Date.today)
```

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk That's correct, I was just looking up the mysql variant, but this should work in postgres.

Comment: Followup question: How do get due_dates for the next week?

Comment: `where("DATE(assignments.due_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?"
, Date.today.beginning_of_day + 7.days, Date.today.beginning_of_day + 14.days)` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution :

```
{ due_date: (Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day) }
```

Comment: For today, the statement will produce the following SQL, which work with a datetime column  `BETWEEN '2015-05-26 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-26 23:59:59'`

Answer (score 0):

To compare with a datetime column you need to have a DateTime object. However if you compare a for equity with `DateTime.now.beginning_of_day` it will only match assignments with are due at `00:00`.

Instead if you want assigments that are due today you could do:

```
StudentAssignment.joins(:assignment)
         .where(assignments: { 
            due_date: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day 
         })
```

You can create a named scope:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  scope(:due_today) -> {
    where(due_date:DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day )
  }
end
```